# Can I create and use the flutter driver autonomous test as apk

Tags: android, ios, selenium, flutter, flutterdriver

I use flutter driver to test the UIs in my application autonomously.
Instead of creating this process with commands from the terminal constantly
Is it possible to start the test once I create an apk and every time I open the application?
Can I create and use it as apk
I want something like this, but I don't know if it's possible.